# New to Spyder and unsure why < isn’t working for triggering “less than” in my script

Tags: command

Mainly practicing and getting a feel for things, I’m currently a software student and have never worked with Spyder before. Maybe I’m missing something or unsure how this works, but any insight is appreciated. Here’s my code;

```
Heat_Level = 13
Heat_Integrity = 100
Hull_Integrity = 100
print("Temperature critical, taking heat damage.", "Hull integrity at", Hull_Integrity + Heat_Level - Hull_Integrity, "percent.")
if Hull_Integrity < 20:
    print("Seek immediate repairs.")
elif Hull_Integrity == 0:
    print("Ship compromised, integrity 0")
```

My problem is that I get my Hull_Integrity variable to 13, which should prompt the message from;

```
if Hull_Integrity < 20:
    print(“Seek immediate repairs.”)
```

When running the code I only get results from everything before that line. Anyone know if I’m missing something or not using the proper command for less than?

Comment: It appears that you have just set `Heat_Level` to 13, not `Hull_Integrity`. Fix that and `Seek immediate repairs.` gets printed.

Comment: As a complete aside to your question, you should only user lower case characters in variable names in Python, according to [PEP-8](https://realpython.com/python-pep8/)

Comment: Thanks, David Buck, I’ll try that out, and thanks for the tip. I’ll be sure to keep it lowercase.